# OFFSET() + ROW() wont give the desired result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row, offset

I'm trying to combine the OFFSET function with the ROW function but they don't work as expected.

If I try:

```
{=OFFSET(A1:F1,ROW(F6)-1;0)}
```

It gives me the wrong results giving only an array constant with 1 column.

```
'It returns:
{0}
```

Else if I use:

```
{=OFFSET(A1:F1,5,0)}
```

It works perfectly and returns an array constant with the corresponding column values of the offset row.

```
'Would return:
{0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

If *ROW* returns a number why the hell doesn't this work as it should?

Comment: What's the entire formula you're trying to use? (assuming this is part of a larger formula)?

Comment: @BigBen
That is exactly what i tried to ensure it was not another thing that was causing the problem, but as simple as i wrote in the question it works like that.

Comment: I think you'll find that ROW() returns an array, not a scalar - in the case of ROW(F6) you _think_ it's returning 6 but it's actually returning {6} which is then throwing off your OFFSET because it needs a scalar value for the row/column offset components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my previous comment, ROW returns an array not a scalar value (ie in your formula ROW(F6) returns {6} not 6, which stuffs up your OFFSET (as it requires a scalar for the rows/column offsets).

Per https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/row-function-returning-array-though-it-should-not/fcce040c-c297-43d9-a02e-a0038b6be5e0 if you wrap the ROW(F6) in a SUM or MAX it should fix the problem ie
`=OFFSET(A1:F1,SUM(ROW(F6))-1;0)`

Comment: Thanks!
I ended up writing a function that used Application.Caller as a substitute.
I even tried using Value for warpping the Row function, and probably would have never figure out that using Max would fix it.